# 7 random characters are sitting on a bench.

Tags: probability

(A) What is the probability that Doggo will not sit at the ends?

-I think it's 5!/7! because Doggo can't sit at the ends (2) so subtract 2 from the total and that's the numerator.

(B) What is the probability that the Joker and Batman will not sit next to each other?

- Probability that they will sit next to each other is 2!*6!/7! so I would subtract that from 7! to get 35276/7.

I'm not sure if these are correct, and it would really help if you can tell me why it's incorrect, and any other ways to do these problems will help too!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming I've understood your question correctly:

$(A)$ There are $6!$ ways in which Doggo will sit on the left edge, as he goes on the left edge and the remaining 6 can go in any order. Similarly, there are $6!$ ways he can sit on the right edge. So there are $2\times 6!$ ways he sit on the edge. So probability he does not sit on the end is $\frac{7!-2(6!)}{7!}=\frac{7-2}{7}=\frac57$

Alternatively we note that he is equally likely to go in any place, so $5/7$ chance he goes in the middle.

$(B)$ You're correct that the probablility that they will sit next to each other is $\frac{2!\times 6!}{7!}$ but since we're dealing with probabilities the probability that they will not sit next to each other is $1-\frac{2!\times 6!}{7!}=\frac57$ once again.

If ever you get a probability (much) bigger than $1$ you've gone wrong somewhere.

Comment: Oh, I see now. For B, I subtracted the entire thing by 7! rather than 1. So, for future reference, it's always subtracted by 1 to get the answer to B, right?

Comment: Yes, since dealing with probabilities.